# React: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this error when I run my code.

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

And here's the code . it's referencing.

```
  69 | }
  70 | 
  71 | addQuestion = () => {
> 72 |   this.setState({numQuestions: this.state.numQuestions + 1});
  73 |  }
  74 | 
  75 | render() {

  131 | <div className="field">
  132 |     <div className="endButtons">
  133 |       <button id="addQuestionButton"
> 134 |         onClick={this.addQuestion()}>Add Question</button>
  135 |       <input
  136 |         type="submit"
  137 |         value="Submit"

   5 | import App from './App';
   6 | import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
   7 | 
>  8 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
   9 | registerServiceWorker();
  10 | 
  11 |
```

I set my stuff up the way the articles on the actual React site said to and it "came" with this neat console type thing, that's where I came up with the above code. I'm very new to React, JSX, and Javascript (and just programing in general) and I don't really understand what this means so if you could also explain a little that would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: this.addQuestion() is fired everytime the component is rendered and since addQuestion sets the state it will re-render the component, resulting in a loop. onClick={() => this.addQuestion()} should fix it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are calling `this.addQuestion` in your render method, which in turn calls `setState` which will result in a new render, and the indefinite loop continues.

You want to give `onClick` a function reference, not call it directly.

```
<button id="addQuestionButton" onClick={this.addQuestion}>Add Question</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

`this.addQuestion()` invoked every time the component re-renders, thus causing a loop.

Change the method `this.addQuestion()` to `() => this.addQuestion()`

```
<button id="addQuestionButton" onClick={() => this.addQuestion()}>Add Question</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The printed error message is quite self-explanatory. When you start your app, the `this.addQuestion()` is invoked directly, which triggers a re-render. The re-render will then invoke the same function again, and the loop continues until React has enough of it.

Just like @Tholle said in his answer, simply give it the *reference* to the function you want. Don't invoke it.

Also, whenever you are setting a state variable whose value depends on the previous state, it is recommended to pass a callback function to `setState()` rather than an object. So instead do:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({numQuestions: prevState.numQuestions + 1}));
```

This is irrelevant from the error you are getting, but still something I would advise you to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind in the constructor.

```
bind set: this.delta = this.delta.bind(this)
```

Comment: not the problem.  This could be necessary for `onClick={this.addQuestion}` solution to work depending on how addQuestion method is implemented; but the way OP wrote it `addQuestion = () => ...` relies on [public class field initializers running in constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65210831/javascript-class-syntax-and-binding-this-in-methods) and works without explicit bind().  And `onClick={() => this.addQuestion()}` callback would always work. The problem was just unintended _immediate_ call at render time.

Answer (score -1):

> Your function **this.addQuestion**
>   call at render time but as per your requirement it should call on while button onClick.

*try this...*

`<button id="addQuestionButton" onClick={this.addQuestion}>Add Question</button>`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question's [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51196357/4638529) seems to be very similar to your answer. Is your answer providing any additional information than the accepted answer?

Comment: Yes!!! My answer basically based on @dorkycam requirement.. where we should used this.addQuestion and this.addQuestion().Im suggesting him to call function like onClick={this.addQuestion}.

Comment: @SantoshPanda, that's what the accepted answer is already suggesting. Your answer does not appear to add any additional information.